# Turbolinks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

Recently I have been reading about turbolinks which is deprecated but one should have a proper knowledge . I have read that turbolinks replaces the body of the requested page with the body of the current page and merges the head. The primary speed comes from not having to reload the assets like js or css files which are present in both heads of the requested and current page and are same.
My confusion is some seniors say that turbolinks does not replaces the body rather it replaces the sections in the body. And If there is a full body swapping, then its almost same as even if you are sending a normal request instead of ajax.
Now I am confused. Please give your expert opinion regarding the workflow of the turbolinks.

Comment: You should probably clarify with other people if you really mean turbolinks, or the newer thing that is just called `turbo`, the new approach does indeed allow you to only change parts of the page by using turbo_frames or turbo_streams, see https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames

Comment: Not turbo, just explicitly talking about turbolinks.

Answer (score 1):

[By default](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#navigating-with-turbolinks) during rendering, Turbolinks replaces the current `<body>` element outright and merges the contents of the `<head>` element. The JavaScript window and document objects, and the HTML `<html>` element, persist from one rendering to the next

[However](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/wiki/Turbolinks-5-FAQ#why-did-you-remove-partial-replacement), Turbolinks has concept of "permanent" elements via the `data-turbolinks-permanent` annotation. Placing this annotation on any element with an ID allows that element to persist across page changes

[Permanent elements](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads) persist across page loads, so that any changes you make to those elements do not need to be reapplied after navigation

Designate permanent elements by giving them an HTML id and annotating them with data-turbolinks-permanent

```
<div id="cart-counter" data-turbolinks-permanent>1 item</div>
```

Before each render, Turbolinks matches all permanent elements by `id` and transfers them from the original page to the new page, preserving their data and event listeners